# Javascript endess loop only in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, infinite-loop

When running my javascript program on IE, it loops forever.

It works on Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

There is a similar question in Stackoverflow, but here the suggestion was to remove the functionname of the embedded function. I don't have a name on it.

Here an excerpt of the function to set up an asynchronous httprequest. 'rq' is the request object, with open() already called, but not send().

I am trying to set a response function. I am using the 'self' var so that the function will have the same this pointer (also member of same object as calling function).

```
var self = this;
rq.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    self._reqStateChange(rq);     // *
}                                 // *
this._req[sl]=rq;
rq.send(null);
return true;
```

IE endless loops the two lines marked with // *, also the first return in the embedded function:

```
this._reqStateChange = function(rq)
{
    if( (!rq) || rq.readyState!=4 )
        return;    // exits here every time.
```

IE 9.0, using built-in debugger.

no jQuery or any other libs inplace.

I have no idea. thanks for helping. I would like to understand the logic here...

Note:

I just built a little script to see if the self-construct is wrong. That works. Seems to be related to the onreadystatechange function. Everytime it exits, it is immediately called again.

This code does NOT lock  up in IE:

```
someObject = function()
{
    this.callback = function(){}
    this.funcCallsCallback = function()
    {
        // call the callback
        this.callback();
    };
}
muell = new function()
{
    this.value = 42;
    this.test = function()
    {
        var rq = new someObject();
        var self = this;
        rq.callback = function()
        {
            self.endFunc();
        }
        // now:
        rq.funcCallsCallback();
    };
    this.endFunc = function()
    {
        alert("called! value="+this.value.toString());
    };
}

muell.test();
```

Comment: Where's the code for `_reqStatChange`

Comment: Forgot the first lines of the other function... Adding...

Comment: I am not sure what is happening here, but I guess the self and this are playing games. I can only suggest trying moving this._reqStateChange to an anonymous function in place and using it instead. Can you give the complete codes of these two functions?

Comment: Instead of "self._reqStateChange(rq);", can you try "self._reqStateChange(this);"?